# Mouse scroll zoom not working on dashboard chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, zooming

I would like to add mouse scroll zooming, but the `explorer` function doesn't seem to work in the chart options. How can I get mouse scroll to zoom the chart?

```
explorer: {
    axis: 'horizontal',
    keepInBounds: true,
    maxZoomIn: 4.0
}
```

Here's my chart:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');


  var data1 = 5;
  var data2 = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    data.addRows([
      [i, i + data1, i + data2]

    ]);
  }

  var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
      title: 'Průběh tlaku v čase',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Čas',
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#333'
        },
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 80
      },
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          height: 40,
          width: 600,
          chartArea: {
            width: '90%'
          }
        }
      },
      colors: ['#D44E41']
    }

  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',

  });

  function setOptions(wrapper) {
    wrapper.setOption('width', 600);
  }

  dash.bind([control], [chart]);
  dash.draw(data);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function() {});
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard"></div>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
<div id="control_div"></div>
```

[View at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5h7jxqq8/71/)

Comment: It looks like you've already got a [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) working to zoom in on the chart. Can you help clarify what trouble you're having?

Comment: i would like to add scroll mouse zoom - but explorer function didn't worked in options 
explorer: {
            axis: 'horizontal',
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 4.0
          }

Answer (score 1):

I had some success by adding `explorer` to the [options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for the [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class). Mouse scrolling now zooms the chart, but it does not update the `ChartRangeFilter` display. It would be nice if the mouse zoomed both the chart and the range filter simultaneously to keep them in sync.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['controls', 'charteditor']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');


  var data1 = 5;
  var data2 = 100;
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    data.addRows([
      [i, i + data1, i + data2]

    ]);
  }

  var dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard'));

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'control_div',
    options: {
      title: 'Průběh tlaku v čase',
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Čas',
        titleTextStyle: {
          color: '#333'
        },
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 80
      },
      filterColumnIndex: 0,
      ui: {
        chartOptions: {
          height: 40,
          width: 600,
          chartArea: {
            width: '90%'
          }
        }
      },
      colors: ['#D44E41']
    }

  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      explorer: {
        axis: 'horizontal',
        keepInBounds: true,
        maxZoomIn: 4.0
      }
    }
  });

  function setOptions(wrapper) {
    wrapper.setOption('width', 600);
  }

  dash.bind([control], [chart]);
  dash.draw(data);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function() {});
}
```

```css
#chart_div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="control_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks very much :) it works - it would be nice keep both zoom, but i'm beginner is JS, but that's all what i need right now